# Tor relay and apache

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, web-hosting

I am running a tor relay on my desktop (Ubuntu 14.04) as well as using the tor browser to access the internet myself. I would like to host a web site using apache on the same computer. Are there any risks in doing this? Will the relay or my web browsing be compromised?

Comment: A part of your question is answered here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1699/88

Comment: Thanks for the link Jens. It seems that running a relay on the same computer as your tor browser doesn't increase your risk and may possibly be beneficial though there is some uncertainty. I haven't been able to find anything though relating to running apache and a relay on the same computer. I wonder if this has been studied?

Answer (score 1):

Running a Tor relay, a Tor Browser and a web server on the same host does not make either of them more vulnerable or identifiable. But running a relay means that your IP is publicly advertised, which could get any internet-facing service on your host more 'attention' than it would get otherwise.